# TeX distribution licenses

Tags: miktex, texlive, distributions

I want to install a Tex distribution on my company-issued computer. My company requires me to register the license of the software before I install and use it.

To my knowledge, MikTex and Tex live are my two options. I see these both refer to FSF in their license page, but they still don't have a clear list of the licenses comprising it.

Anyone know which licenses one of those distributions have (or know where to ask for them) so I can use them?

Comment: Both are 'open' licensed _but_ there is no one license covering all of the code: each (La)TeX package author sets their own license. As such, the best you are likely to get is https://www.tug.org/texlive/copying.html.

Comment: Suppose you want to install Fontforge. There is no place where you can “register the license” for the simple fact that there is no company that licenses the software.

Comment: @JosephWright so there's no list of all licenses used for all packages included in Tex live? Or maybe pick those packages that I need and try to find their specific licenses?

Comment: @Panos Even a basic install will be problematic: you have the license for TeX itself (essentially public domain), for pdfTeX/LuaTeX (GPL), for fonts (vary, but SIL is common), for LaTeX (LPPL), for Lua (MIT), etc.